# PostgreSQL PDO insert into array type

Tags: php, sql, arrays, postgresql, pdo

I'm trying to use PHP PDO to insert values into a PostgreSQL database, but encounter the following error message:

```
SQLSTATE[22P02]: Invalid text representation: 7 ERROR: array value must start with "{" or dimension information
```

The field type is a [PostgreSQL Array](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/arrays.html) .

Here is my code (simplified):

```
try {
  $sql='INSERT INTO table (fieldName, foo) VALUES (?, ?)';
  $fieldName=array('1','2');
  $data=array($fieldName, 'bar'); # fieldName is array type in PostgreSQL
  $STH = $conn->prepare($sql);          
  $STH->execute($data);
catch(PDOException $e) {
  # Handle exception
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why `$data=array(array('1','2'));` instead of `$data=array('1','2');`?

Comment: I updated the question. The fieldname variable is stored as an array in PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just in case anyone ever comes across this, the solution was to implode the array and add {}.

```
$fieldName='{'.implode(",",$fieldName).'}';
```

Comment: A user can provide data that either makes your database generate an error or gets processed as a different array from what the database client had: ['hello \\','world'] in php would become '{hello world}' in PostgreSQL, when it should be '{hello \\,world}'. Of course, I've never used PgSQL, so I could be wrong, but this seems right based on what I've read in the documentation. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/arrays.html

Comment: I downvoted this answer because it does not escape values. If `$fieldName` contains coommas and other special chars, it will not be interpreted as expected!

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread but it is the first Google hit for "php Postgres PDO array", so I'll add my answer to this. The problem with Matt's answer is that there is no inherent sanitization with implode. So if $fieldname contains quotes, commas, mustache brackets, etc. it will create an invalid value. See below for an example of how to handle array data with proper PDO:

```
// Connect to PostgreSQL database and create test table /////
$dsn = "pgsql:host=$host;dbname=$db;user=$user;password=$pwd";
$psql = new PDO($dsn);

if($psql == null){throw new Exception("Error, db connection returned null.");}
// Set errormode to exceptions
$psql->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$sql_table = "
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS testarray (
        id         SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
        something  TEXT,
        test1      TEXT[]
    )";
$q_table = $psql->prepare($sql_table);
$q_table->execute();
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// Create a new row and get it's ID
$sql_new = "INSERT INTO testarray (something) VALUES ('stuff') RETURNING id";
$q_new = $psql->prepare($sql_new);
$q_new->execute();
$r_new = $q_new->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$id = $r_new[0]['id'];

$myarray = array("Test1", "Test2", "test3", "testing4", "TEST5");

// Use a PDO for efficiency and ease of use
// Use the ARRAY_APPEND SQL function to use PDO to add to an array
$sql_up = "UPDATE testarray SET test1 = ARRAY_APPEND(test1, :arr) WHERE id = :id";
$q_up = $psql->prepare($sql_up);
$q_up->bindParam(":id", $id);

// Loop through each element, binding it to the PDO and executing again
foreach($myarray as $elem){
    $q_up->bindParam(":arr", $elem);
    $q_up->execute();
}
```

And in your database now:

```
testing=# SELECT * FROM testarray;
 id | something |               test1                
----+-----------+------------------------------------
  1 | stuff     | {Test1,Test2,test3,testing4,TEST5}
(1 row)

testing=#
```

Comment: Seems rather hacky, but at least it seems like it would reliably put in the data as expected without a chance for errors.

Answer (score 1):

I recently had call to achieve something similar. I would convert a PHP array into json using json_encode and bind the param or value so it escapes all values - thus removing chance of SQL injection.

```
$st->bindValue(':arr',json_encode(["jam sandwich","ham sandwich","cheese sandwich"]),\PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Then in the PDO statement using array aggregation functions to build the array from json functions.

E.g.

```
SELECT array_agg(ar) FROM 
jsonb_array_elements_text('["jam sandwich","ham sandwich","cheese sandwich"]') ar;
```

You could use this in a CTE (Common Table Expression) to peform insert, update or whatever in one single query, while making this safe as all values are escaped.